# Why are my graph results not matching when I adjust the group_by function?

Tags: r

So I was about to submit a case-study, but when I looked through the numbers, I realized there are massive inconsistencies.

So I was testing some different cases and realized when I started to add more column names into my group_by function, the numbers started to decrease dramatically.

I suspect it has something to do with summarize() as I have been using that without fully understanding its usage.

So I did some A/B Testing.

I wrote test_1 to not contain one of the columns "time_of_day"

```
test_1 = annual_2022_v2 %>% 
  group_by(month_of_day, day_of_week, member_casual) %>% 
  summarize(total = sum(ride_length))
```

Where I wrote out

```
total_month_2022 = test_1 %>% 
  ggplot(aes(factor(day_of_week), total, fill=member_casual)) +
  geom_bar(stat = "identity", position = "dodge") + 
  scale_y_continuous(labels = scales::comma) + facet_wrap(~month_of_day) +
  labs(y= "Time (in mins)", x = "Day") + 
  ggtitle("Total Ride Length Per Month")
```

and it gave me this

[image]

Then I tested it with my original code including "time_of_day"

```
ride_time_2022 = annual_2022_v2 %>% 
  group_by(month_of_day, day_of_week, time_of_day, member_casual) %>% 
  summarize(total = sum(ride_length))
```

Where I ran

```
total_month_2022 = ride_time_2022 %>% 
  ggplot(aes(factor(day_of_week), total, fill=member_casual)) +
  geom_bar(stat = "identity", position = "dodge") + 
  scale_y_continuous(labels = scales::comma) + facet_wrap(~month_of_day) +
  labs(y= "Time (in mins)", x = "Day") + 
  ggtitle("Total Ride Length Per Month")
```

And it shows this

[image]

So there is not much of an adjustment of the actual "data shape", but rather the scaling and it is weird to see it scaled down so low. It isn't consistent to the decrease of the scale.

So I don't understand. I didn't think adding a new element in the group_by function would change the output that much as I only added time_of_day which allows me to see data from different time periods throughout the day.

Maybe it is because I am not coding in the proper way? Is Summarize() the issue?

Edit:

I decided to check the actual dataset and the numbers seem consistent.

[image]

[image]

For example, The January Casuals would add up to each other, so I am having a hard time understanding why the graphs show a different value.

Comment: Subdividing your data by another dimension would typically make there be fewer observations within each group, and thus smaller total ride_lengths. For instance, I might have eaten 21 meals last week, but if I looked divided the week by days I only had 3 per day. In one case there was one week with 21 meals, in the other there were 7 days with 3 meals each. If I then plotted it without showing the separate days, so that the different days were overplotted on top of each other, it would look like my totals were 1/7th as big.

Comment: Makes sense John. Thank you for the logic clarification.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The issue is that you second aggregated data contains values by `time_of_day`, i.e. in your ggplot you get a bar for each category of `time_of_day`. But these bars don't get stacked (i.e. ggplot2 will not sum the values) but instead are plotted on top each other, hence the scale is different from your first code.

Below is a minimal reproducible example of the issue based on `mtcars`.

The first plot shows the sum of `mpg` by `cyl` and `gear`.

```r
library(ggplot2)
library(dplyr, warn=FALSE)

mtcars2 <- mtcars |>
  mutate(across(c(cyl, gear, am), factor))

mtcars2 |>
  group_by(cyl, gear) |>
  summarise(mpg = sum(mpg)) |>
  ggplot(aes(cyl, mpg, fill = gear)) +
  geom_col(position = "dodge")
#> `summarise()` has grouped output by 'cyl'. You can override using the `.groups`
#> argument.
```

[image]

Now we add `am` as a third grouping group and use the "same" plotting code, i.e. to make the difference visible I mapped on the `color` aes and set the fill to `"transparent"`. Here we see, that for `gear=4` we now have two bars and that the values don't sum up:

```r
mtcars2 |>
  group_by(cyl, gear, am) |>
  summarise(mpg = sum(mpg)) |>
  ggplot(aes(cyl, mpg, color = gear)) +
  geom_col(position = "dodge", fill = "transparent") +
  geom_text(aes(label = mpg, group = gear), 
            position = position_dodge(width = .9), color = "black")
#> `summarise()` has grouped output by 'cyl', 'gear'. You can override using the
#> `.groups` argument.
```

[image]

One option to fix that would be to use `stat_summary` to compute the `sum`:

```r
mtcars2 |>
  group_by(cyl, gear, am) |>
  summarise(mpg = sum(mpg)) |>
  ggplot(aes(cyl, mpg, fill = gear)) +
  stat_summary(
    geom = "bar", fun = "sum",
    position = "dodge"
  )
#> `summarise()` has grouped output by 'cyl', 'gear'. You can override using the
#> `.groups` argument.
```

[image]

Comment: Hello Stefan, that makes perfect sense to me now. I should have considered the possibility that my results aren't stacking up and I was tunnel-visioned in not realizing it. I will try it out. Thank you.

Comment: That did the trick. Thank you, now I understand why it didn't work. Basically like you and John said, I didn't factor the fact I have separated the data, thus it didn't initially include it. This was a huge help. Thank you.